# Transfering Data in MS Access Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an ever growing and changing database that reflects a permits passed by the State and EPA.
As the database changes and updates I need to transfer the relevant information.

The script does two things; first it checks which fields are the same and creates a list of fields and data that will be inserted into the new database. Second to insert the data into the new database.

Problem is I cannot get it to insert. I have matched everything like it says online in various ways but i get error ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)').

I cannot figure out how to prevent it.

Code:

```
import pyodbc

importDatabase = r"J:\ENVIRO FIELD\AccessDatabases\MS4\MS4 Town Databases\~Template\MS4_Apocalypse Import DEV 1.accdb"

"Create the Import Database Connection"
connectionImport = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %(importDatabase))
cursorImport = connectionImport.cursor()


"####---Outfall Section---####"

"Import the outfall names into the new database"

tbl = "tbl_Outfall_1_Profile"

exportList = []
importList = []
for row in cursorImport.columns(table = "tblExportMigration_Outfall_1_Profile"):
    field = row.column_name
    exportList.append(field)

for row in cursorImport.columns(table = "tbl_Outfall_1_Profile"):
    field = row.column_name
    importList.append(field)

matchingList = []
for field in exportList:
    if field != "outfallID":
        if field in importList:
            matchingList.append(field)
    else:
        continue

sqlValue = ""
for field in matchingList:
    sqlValue += "[%s], " %(field)

sqlValue = sqlValue[:-2]
sql = "SELECT %s from %s" %(sqlValue, "tblExportMigration_Outfall_1_Profile")

for rowA in cursorImport.execute(sql):
    tupleList = list(rowA)
    tupleList = ["" if i == None else i for i in tupleList]
    tupleValues = tuple(tupleList)
    sqlUpdate = """INSERT INTO tbl_Outfall_1_Profile (%s) Values %s;""" %(sqlValue, tupleValues)
    cursorImport.execute(sqlUpdate)

cursorImport.close()
```

This is the sql string I create

"INSERT INTO tbl_Outfall_1_Profile ([profile_OutfallName], [profile_HistoricalName1], [profile_HistoricalName2], [profile_HistoricalName3], [profile_HistoricalName4]) Values ('756', '', '', '', '');"

Comment: First off, don't use string substitution ("dynamic SQL") to insert column values. Use a proper *parameterized query* instead, e.g., `sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (⁦col1, col2) Values (?, ?);"` followed by `cursorImport.execute(sqlUpdate, (param1, param2))`. Do a web search for "Little Bobby Tables" for more information.

Comment: @GordThompson I cannot just hard wire the information into the query. I could create a section of the script to generate the ?'s. However the tables field names have a high potential of being updated and changed due to the nature of the permit. I have to account for this in the system or there will be an issue further down the road. I did not create nor write the permit but I have to have the system reflect it.

Comment: So you may still need to use dynamic SQL for the column list since parameter substitution only works for column *values*, not column *names*, but you still should use parameters for the values.

Comment: @GordThompson
Is this what you are referring to to do:

sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO tbl_Outfall_1_Profile ([profile_OutfallName], [profile_HistoricalName1], [profile_HistoricalName2], [profile_HistoricalName3], [profile_HistoricalName4]) Values (?,?,?,?,?);" 

cursorImport.execute(sqlUpdate, (tupleValues))

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Comment: @GordThompson Awesome I am on the right track then! This is the error I get back Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not update; currently locked by user 'admin' on machine 'HAR-DELL-JCON'. (-1102) (SQLExecDirectW)"). or I will get ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235352/discussion-between-jake-and-gord-thompson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what @Gord Thompson said I was actually able to create a dynamic parameter flow

First created a module to create the ?

```
def Defining_Paramters(length):
    parameterString = ""
for x in range(1,length):
    parameterString += "?, "
parameterString += "?"

return parameterString
```

Then stuck it into the string for the sql update

```
sqlUpdate = sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) Values (%s);" %(table, sqlFrameworkSubStr, parameters)
```

Run the cursor and commit it

```
cursorTo.execute(sqlUpdate, (dataTuple))
connectionTo.commit()
```

It would seem that you have to create the query in its entirety then have your data in tuple format for entry

Answer (score 0):

> This is the sql string [I think] I create

Try this:

```
sqlUpdate = """INSERT INTO tbl_Outfall_1_Profile (%s) Values (%s);""" %(sqlValue, tupleValues)
```

or perhaps:

```
sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO tbl_Outfall_1_Profile (%s) Values (%s);" %(sqlValue, tupleValues)
```

Comment: I tried it out but still get the 42000 Error

Comment: Perhaps you can't insert empty strings `Values ('756', '', '', '', '')`. Most likely, they should be _Null_.

Comment: ( cc: @Jake ) - That would be a different error: "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Field 'Donor.DonorName' cannot be a zero-length string. (-3702) (SQLExecDirectW)"